# Linq Query list within a list and exclude sub-list data

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list of phone object that is within a list of phonegroups. There is a property on the phone "is4GCompatible".

I would like to query the phonegroups and let me all the phonegroups that contains phones that are 4GComptible. The linq query works to certain extend but it also includes the phones that are not compatible which is not what i am looking.

Live Example of the code: http://rextester.com/OKB8502

Please advise?

Comment: Bad Request..... Pleas show your code here.

Comment: I got bad request in chrome only. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your sample code to get the groups that contain phones that are 4Gcompatible:

```
phonegroups.Where(p => p.phones.Any(x => x.is4GCompatible == true)).ToList();
```

If you want to exclude the phones that are not 4GCompatible you will need to construct new groups containing only those phones that are 4GCompatible:

```
        phonegroups.Where(pg => pg.phones.Any(p => p.is4GCompatible))
                   .Select(pg => new phonegroup
                       {
                         groupName = pg.groupName,
                         phones = pg.phones.Where(p => p.is4GCompatible).ToList()
                       })
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, you want to take groups that contain phones that are 4GComptible. Use `Where` + `Any`:

```
var all4GComptible = phoneGroups.Where(pg => pg.Any(p => p.is4GCompatible));
```